# C# Generic Objects Compareing

Tags: c#, generics, compare

This is generic class to compare two objects with a user defined property, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
public class ObjectComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private string _propertyName;

    private string PropertyName
    {
        get { return _propertyName; }
        set
        {
            _propertyName = value;
            PropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(PropertyName);
        }
    }

    public ObjectComparer(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    private PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }

    public int GetHashCode(T type)
    {
        if (type== null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return PropertyInfo.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(T obj1, T obj2)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, null) || ReferenceEquals(obj2, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj1, null) == PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj2, null);
    }
}
```

Issue 1)`type == null` (Possible compare of value type with `null`)

Issue 2)Use `ReferenceEquals` in this position is correct?

Update

"Word" class:

```
public class Word
{
    public string EnglishText { get; set; }
    public string LocalText { get; set; }
    public string EditedText { get; set; }
}
```

Usage :

```
var except = Program.Localizer.DefaultLanguage.Words.Except(CurrentSelectedLanguage.Words, new ObjectComparer<Word>("EnglishText"));
```

Number of different objects based on the "EnglishName" is not correct.

---

Class authentic and Modified below.
Special thanks to  Sriram Sakthivel

```
public class ObjectComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private string _propertyName;

    private string PropertyName
    {
        get { return _propertyName; }
        set
        {
            _propertyName = value;
            PropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(PropertyName);
        }
    }

    public ObjectComparer(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    private PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return PropertyInfo.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(T obj1, T obj2)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, null) || ReferenceEquals(obj2, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals(PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj1, null),
                             PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj2, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean by  _not work correctly_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetHashCode` is wrong. You're calling `PropertyInfo.GetHashCode` It should be using the Property value instead.

```
public int GetHashCode(T obj)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    var value = PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
    return value == null ? 0 : value.GetHashCode();
}
```

Also you can get rid of *Possible compare of value type with null* warning from resharper using `object.ReferenceEquals`

`GetHashCode` parameter is named as `type`, which is misleading, So I renamed it to `obj`

Update:

If you need to use value comparison you must use `Object.Equals` method as opposed to using `==` operator for `object` type

```
public bool Equals(T obj1, T obj2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, null) || ReferenceEquals(obj2, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return object.Equals(PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj1, null), 
                         PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj2, null));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work means? What happens? Otherwise we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: This code works correctly.I did not pay enough attention.Thank you very much for your help.